# How to save data in DB with a form using Varien_Object?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to save all the data that comes from the form, plus a few additional fields of type (user_id, created_at, etc...).
How do i do it through Varien_Object ?

```
 public function postAction()
{
    $paths = 'RonisBT_Feedback_Model_Source_Paths';

    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($post) {

        $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        $user_agent = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent();
        $remote_ip = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
        $subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('subject');
        $other_subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('other');
        $message = $this->getRequest()->getPost('message');
        $created_at = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        try {
            $validate = Mage::getModel('feedback/validation')->validation_form($name, $message, $subject, $email);
            if ($validate === true) {
                $captcha = Mage::getModel('feedback/captcha')->check_captcha();
                if ($captcha === true) {
            $data = array(
                'user_agent' => $user_agent,
                'remote_ip' => $remote_ip,
                'created_at' => $created_at,
            );
            $post = array_merge($post, $data);
            $postObject = Mage::getModel('feedback/block');
            $postObject->setData($post);
            $postObject->save();
```

As you think it is normal that you used array merge?

Ressource model

```
<?php
class RonisBT_Feedback_Model_Resource_Block extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('feedback/block', 'feedback_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of data is that? Do you have a custom table in the database for that? Did you create a model for that?

Comment: Yes, the table in the bd created.

Comment: model / ressource model created?

Comment: yes,created model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the model created you should be able to create the object (as you have done already in your code), just set the data using `setData` and call the save method. You don't need an additional VarienObject for saving the data.

Something like this should woork for you:

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
if ($post) {
    $feedbackBlock = Mage::getModel('feedback/block');

    $user_agent = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent();
    $remote_ip = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
    $created_at = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $feedbackBlock->setData('your_table_column_name','whatevervalue');
    $feedbackBlock->setData('your_table_column_name2',$post['whateverkey']);
    $feedbackBlock->setCreatedAt($created_at); //similar to $feedbackBlock->setData('created_at',$created_at);
    //add other data in the same style
    $feedbackBlock->save();

}
```

Comment: It turned out to do so.
Normal option using merge arrays?

Comment: And how do I transfer the "feedback_id" bd records to the message body?

Comment: yes, merging should be ok. Regarding the "feedback_id":  After the save() method has been called you should be able to get the id using `$feedbackBlock->getId()`